# Change all TextField values in all symbols in library of FlashIDE document

Tags: flash, jsfl

I need to change text in all textfields in my .fla file (Flash CS3).
Looks like i should call JSFL function "fl.findObjectInDocByType("text", fl.getDocumentDOM())" and it would return all elements, but it returns zero length array.
I there any another way to iterate threw all library items, and change values of TextField's in MovieClips ?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ? I also have a need for this

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me, when run on an open FLA from the commands menu:

```
var doc = fl.getDocumentDOM();
var textFieldArray = fl.findObjectInDocByType("text", doc);
fl.trace (textFieldArray.length+ "text Fields found in "+ doc.name);
```